# How to make sure the shopify app proxy subpath is unique among all other apps' proxy?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Imagine this scenario:
There are 2 shopify apps installed in a store. Both uses app proxy:

- App 1:

  - Subpath prefix: apps
  - Subpath: api
- App 2:

  - Subpath prefix: apps
  - Subpath: api

Now if app 1 fetches to `/apps/api`, there is no guarantee that it'll fetch to App 1's server and not App 2's. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

In that hilarious scenario, both apps with that proxy would receive the payload you sent it. Since you control the front-end, you would see the problem. Then, you'd just change the end-point in the Admin for that App and one of the proxies, and you are totally allowed to do that. So you'd activate App1 when you need it with it's payload, and App2 with its payload, and be fine. Fun!

Comment: What did you mean by changing the endpoint in the admin for that app and one of the proxies?

I tested yesterday and only 1 app receives it. However, I’m not sure how shopify determines which app receives the payload. 

Another problem is that the merchant is able to modify the proxy sub path from the app settings in the shopify admin. Is there a way to get the subpath via liquid?

Comment: You pointed out what I pointed out. The merchant can change the subpath and you'll never know. Also, if you have apps/api in one case and you're wondering what happened to the second one, you can guess and try apps/api-1 and you might be surprised to see Shopify just appended a "-1" to distinguish end points. Or, maybe not...